# Asynchronous and callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, express

I'm new in this JavaScript language and stack overflow also.I watched many videos and blogs about synchronous, asynchronous and callbacks but here is my doubt which I'm not able to clear that if synchronous means code should be in sequential order and every step of code should wait for previous step and asynchronous means we don't have to wait for anything then when it comes to callback function .For example we have to fetch some data from the database so suppose we made a program in which we pass a function as a callback function and after fetching the data this callback function will start.So in this case callback also have to wait to do their task till the whole data is load so how can be this thing is asynchronous and not synchronous because we usually don't wait in the case of asynchronous?

Example:

```
// Callback Function Example
function greet(name, myFunction) {
console.log('Hello world');

  // callback function
  // executed only after the greet() is executed
   myFunction(name);
```

}

```
 // callback function
   function sayName(name) {
   console.log('Hello' + ' ' + name);
```

}

```
  // calling the function after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(greet, 2000, 'John', sayName);
```

Let's assume in this example 'hello world' is coming from the backend. So for this hello world data callback has to wait because sometimes it is important to wait for the next step but then here is the doubt that how can be this thing is asynchronous because callback function has to wait for some other function to finish its task.
P.S: I can't post example picture due to reputation issue

Comment: I'd suggest you show a specific real-world code example, not a hypothetical example.  It's hard to understand exactly what code you are asking about.  Questions about code here always get faster and better answers if you show your real code that you're asking about.  Theoretical questions are a lot harder to answer and harder to understand exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You've misunderstood where the waiting doesn't happen.

Given:

```
someImage.addEventListener("load", someFunction);
console.log("This is logged");
```

The **first** line sets up `someFunction` as a callback that will be called when the image has loaded.

The JS engine then runs the **second** line **immediately** without waiting for the image to load and the callback to be called.

Later, the image will load and *then* the callback will be triggered. This will be sometime after the `console.log` statement has logged the string (because the JS engine didn't wait before continuing to the `console.log` statement).

Answer (score 1):

Well good question not because your are confused about synchronous or asynchronous, but more so because your creative mind is trying to understand the edge case under the hood. In my opinion  that is good thing.

Where is that you have been told or may have read or watched etc.

**JavaScript is a scripting language.** You type something it interpreters it and does what ever magic you asked it to do.

**Javascript is a single threaded language.** This means it has one call stack and one memory heap and executes code in order(we will talk about that next) and must finish executing a piece of code before moving onto the next.

**Javascript runs in top down order.** This means when we give it code lets call it entry point before interpreting. Once its gone into to interpreting it will not go back to entry point. Then once its done interpreting it will gather what piece of code you have, whats code is asking to do, move whole chunk into memory and will begin executing line by line. Once in execution mode it will not go back to interpreting.

Lets look at the example below, we have JS engine some bunch of code aka entry point, it interpreted it then executed it. Question is why did it not throw error and how did console.log knew what abc() before it was declared?

**This called heap.** Javascript Engine does a lot of work for us. But the biggest thing is reading our code and executing it. The two main important things in this step are:
We need a place to store and write information — data for our app(variables, objects, etc..)
We need to keep track of what's happening to our code line by line.

This is where a call stack and a Memory heap comes in. call stack is where abc() came before declaration. Interpreter shoved it into heap aka memory and regenerated stack where since functions are first class (so we call them) they get vip treatment and get pushed right to the top, it does not really matter where in calling stack they were defined they get the front row seat in memory. When that happens everything below will automatically know whats above it.

```js
console.log(abc());


function abc(){
return 'I worked even when function was called before it was declared';
}
```

dummy example of what heap sees things and actually runs things.

```js
function abc(){
return 'I worked even when function was called before it was declared';
}
console.log(abc());
```

I hope you get your grasp over this heap and how it shifts things in top down order.
So on execution first it will read the declaration then move on to next point of execution. If it does not have all it needs as it understood it to be it will throw runtime error and halt whole thread. We programmers call it **blocking!**

So lets assume our thread is called jhon, jhon reads the code, shuffles it in order, and starts performing it. we tell jhon a = 1+1 and b = a+1 and then later on ask jhon what is b equals to it will say 3. So jhon's brain looks something like this;

[image]

Next we tell jhon you have another friend to help you while you go on to do next bit of thing just pass on some tasks to this friend called async. Async is different thread from jhons.

```js
async function hello () { return "Hello" };
hello().then((value) => console.log(value));
```

so now both jhon and async brain look something like this;
[image]

very different from first one isn't it? So jhon gave then part to async who is sitting there waiting for it to happen. when it happens it does what ever was asked for in then function.

This is also a layman's way of saying jhon passes then function to friend async which creates its own little heap. when jhon finishes with hello() part of function it then tells async result. Aysnc then uses this result to do something with it and passes a result back to jhon.

Thats all there is to it really. There are lot of different threads running on parallel in JS e.g. download images, AJAX, web workers etc.

[image]

[image]

Now to examplyfy your question. we used main thread jhon who the this has image friend to help out. Jhon passes onload function to image friend and goes on to do what ever it needs to do. image friend works separately without bothering jhon.

```js
var image_friend = new Image;

image_friend.onload = function() {
    alert('image friend loaded image');
}
image_friend .src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQM8eW5EarDCP3wAcVS98nnM-ZCg_qFHtGVLQdj8gz8RHvTsMbECG19vERhMpEbr6dfzhM&usqp=CAU';

alert('jhon is just chilling');
```

john handed everything to image friend and went on to do what next bit of things. As you would notice 'jhon is chilling' always fires before 'image friend loaded image' alert. Even when image is already loaded and is in cache.

[image]

So this is what modern threading looks like. we are just passing instructions to them which few years back we could not. and Now JS has upped its game to pass user defined functions aka async - await to be passed on to thread away from main thread. Previously JS had set of predefined parallel threads e.g. set time out.

```js
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("I was called first but excuted last"); }, 3000);
  
  alert("I was called last but excuted first");
```

Now you can do this with your own function through async - await. Hope you get the idea of how this works.

but there also scenario where passing on work to different threads back fires.

```js
var a ='Iam still loading';

  
   var image_friend = new Image;

    image_friend.onload = function() {
     a = 'loaded';
    }
    image_friend .src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQM8eW5EarDCP3wAcVS98nnM-ZCg_qFHtGVLQdj8gz8RHvTsMbECG19vERhMpEbr6dfzhM&usqp=CAU';

    alert(a);
```

No matter how many times you run it it will always give you I am still loading. that is because a is not updated by main thread in fact it wont even know a was to updated. whole then aka load function was given to image_friend to handle.

Although script did not block but whole asynching failed to achieve what we wanted.